# R having trouble reading in shapefile

Tags: shapefile, r

I am trying to replicate the Kriging interpolation in R with this article's code https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/05/spatial-interpolation-with-and-without-predictors/

I have successfully installed all the packages, and changed the `read_excel` part to read in a shapefile.

```
# Import packages
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(terra)
library(Metrics)
# Interpolation packages
library(gstat)  # Nearest Neighbour, IDW, Kriging
library(fields) # TPS
library(mgcv)   # GAM
library(interp) # TIN
library(automap)# Automatic Kriging
# Load point data
ET_data <- read_sf(dsn = "C:/users/public/test3d.shp", layer = "SHAPEFILE")
# Output extent
ET_sf <- st_as_sf(ET_data, coords=c("x", "y"), crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

However, once I get to the reading in of the shapefiles I keep getting the error

```
Cannot open layer SHAPEFILE
Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  : 
  Opening layer failed.
```

Why would it be failing when I have all associated files in that directory? e.g. shp, shx, prj etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try `ET_data <- st_read(file.path("C:/users/public/test3d.shp"))`

Comment: Worked perfectly - thank you!!